# RiscV CPU, why is it so complicated? (for companies to build)

Tags: cpu, risc-v

I saw an online code for RiscV32 bit processor which consists of nearly 1000 lines of code and supports all know commands like sw, lw, j, etc...

My question is, why companies like Apple need so much time and resources to build a new processor if 1000 lines can be fixed/improved by one engineer only?

Comment: I am talking about the full code of RiscV32 Processor, which has Fetch, Decode, Excute etc...

Comment: Suggest looking at the performance of that thousand line processor.  It will be very poor compared to more sophisticated designs.

Comment: 1000 lines of code might implement the introductory lecture / programmer model of a processor.  Any real performance comes from optimizations, at which point complexity grows rapidly, even for old hat stuff like pipelines with bypass paths, nevermind the sorts of tricks needed to get modern performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they were only simulating the processor, it wouldn't take much at all, a student could do this with the right software. Actually implementing the processor in silicon takes a lot of time and effort. Apple did their own IC design which means that not only do you have to deal with the RISCV architecture, but also designing the transistors and the physical fabrication. Many engineers are needed to do this in many different areas. In addition, for a consumer processor everything needs to be optimized to keep costs down and for performance (power and speed).

Comment: Is there an example of open-source processor where I can take a look at its implementation?

Comment: LEON would be an open source implementation of the SPARC processor

Comment: @albert https://sergeykhbr.github.io/riscv_vhdl/

Comment: I didn't fund the code only explanation, Anyway why it supports only 512kb of RAM isn't this from the 80s?